# Find vector $\vec x$ from a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find $\vec x$ from
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(\vec a_1, \vec x)=\alpha \\ 
[\vec a_2, \vec x]=b \\ 
(\vec a_1, \vec a_2)\ne0 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
So from second equation we get $$x=\phi\vec a_2+\frac{[\vec b, \vec a_2]}{(\vec a_2, \vec a_2)}, \ \phi \in \Bbb R$$
How to connect $\phi$ with remaining equations?

Comment: Does $(x,y)$ mean scalar product and $[x,y]$ vector product?

Comment: Just use the first equation to determine $\phi$.

Comment: ... (ctd from @Math Lover answer) by taking the dot product with $a_1$ of the two sides of your equation.

Comment: @JeanMarie what do you mean?

Comment: By "taking the dot product with $a_1$", I mean that $(a_1,x)=\phi(a_1,\vec a_2)+(a_1,\frac{[\vec b, \vec a_2]}{(\vec a_2, \vec a_2)})$ from which you can extract $\phi = ...$.